# Lookup value in 2-D List in Excel and find last instance

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am in need of some major assistance. I am trying to create a VBA function that will allow me to find the last five instances of a string in a 2-D set of data and return the name of the column that each instance is in.

I have a data workbook which looks like this:
[picture of data worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/050NR.png)

Essentially, every day every employee has a different placement and we input their names into this sheet.  On a separate sheet, pictured below, the name of the employee is entered and their percentages and last 5 placements are shown. I can do simple things in VBA like making functions and the like, however I have no idea how to go about this beast. Any help would be much appreciated.
[Picture of Percentages page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn1oj.png)

data page with info:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF7l2.png)

Comment: Hi some questions for clarification: 1. Can you show an example of the first spreadsheet with some data filled in to demonstrate what last 5 placements look like? 2. your goal is to populate columns `last ... 5th` with the last 5 placements of the person identified in the column `name`? would be interested to help grateful if you could clarify

Comment: Hello, I have added a picture of the data table to show what it will look like. There will be one for each day of the year and will essentially be filled with names like that but more names. As for the second question, that is completely correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it: I was interested to investigate it as some of the microsoft docs/functionality around `FindNext` I think might be bugged.

The function takes as a parameter the name of the person and a range of all the logged palcements. It returns an array of 5 columns so you'll need to familiarise yourself with `ctrl-shift-enter` for array functions

[image]

e.g. Formula for `b13:f13` is `=find_last_5(A13, $A$3:$G$10)`

```
Option Explicit

Function find_last_5(ByVal employee_name As String, ByRef placement_data As Range)
  
  Const number_placements_required = 5
' return array
  Dim placements() As Variant
'redim to required size (1 row by 5 columns)
  ReDim placements(0, number_placements_required - 1)
  Dim i As Long
' initialise return array to #n/a
  For i = 0 To number_placements_required - 1
    placements(0, i) = CVErr(xlErrNA)
  Next i
  
  i = 0
  Dim first_found As String
  Dim found As Range
  
  With placement_data
'search passed array, backwards looking along rows from last/bottom row cell towards the top left
      Set found = .Find(what:=employee_name, _
        after:=placement_data.Range("a1"), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
      
      If Not found Is Nothing Then
          first_found = found.Address
          Do
              placements(0, i) = found.Column
              Set found = .Find(what:=employee_name, _
                after:=found, _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
              i = i + 1
              
' do until 5 found or nothing found or we wrap back to first address found
          Loop While i < number_placements_required And _
          Not found Is Nothing _
          And found.Address <> first_found
      End If
  End With
  
  find_last_5 = placements

End Function
```